# Is there a way to stop a repeating task in Django Background-Tasks

Tags: python-3.x, django, background-task

I've been successful in creating a repeating task in Django Background-Tasks that I can start with a button on my web page.

I know need a way to stop this repeating tasks again with another button.

Reading the documentation and here on stackoverflow I cannot seem to see a way in background-tasks which can eliminate this task again (for my stop button).

What would be a nice clean solution to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

After some help on the Reddit /djangolearning I came to the following solution:

There is a table (model) in the database: background_tasks. This table contains the task queue.

I imported the task model as follows:

```
from background_task.models import Task
```

Next thing I did was look for the task I was trying to kill, and kill it:

```
def kill_background_task(appname, task_name):
    background_tasks =    Task.objects.filter(task_name='appname.background_tasks.task_name')
    for background_task in background_tasks:
        background_task.delete()
```

I opted for this iterable loop to make sure if some task was somehow started twice or even more times they  would all get deleted.